# Assoc Array Error

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I wan't to create a JSON php output from a MySQL, the database contains at least the follow
username, datetime, acctsessiontime

my logic include **$key** that is the username and ASSOC Array base on the "**key**" but
the username contains 2 extra chars at the end _1  , _2 , _3 , etc....

```
$rows = array();
$acctsessiontime=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $key=substr($row['username'], 0, -2);
        $acctsessiontime+=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
        $acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=$acctsessiontime;
        $datetime=$row['datetime'];
        $rows[$key][] = "[$datetime,$acctsessiontimeby[$key]]";
        $rows['All'][]= "[$datetime,$acctsessiontime]";
}
```

the php error:

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in **\xampp\htdocs\intercall\scripts\server_processing2.php** on line **77**

```
$acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
```

the values:

```
$row['username'] /// output user1_1
$key // output user1
$acctsessiontime // output the $$$ calculated a 60seg in a min and 0.20$ by min
$acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
```

Comment: Where did you define `$acctsessiontimeby` as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Leonardo` said you must first define `$acctsessiontimeby` as an array.
But it's not all. `$acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=` operator refers to the value in '$acctsessiontimeby[$key]'. When the key doesn't exist , PHP throws error.

At first you should check if the key exists, so instead of:

```
$acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
```

you should write:

```
$acctsessiontimeby = array(); // before while loop

// ...

if( isset( $acctsessiontimeby[$key] ) ){
    $acctsessiontimeby[$key]+=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
} else {
    $acctsessiontimeby[$key]=round($row['acctsessiontime']/60*.20,2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer just add Leonardo declaration $acctsessiontimeby=array(); //before the while and now I don't need my workaround...of call the same procedure 4 times XP